# An error occured when I add android platform to my cordova project. Hope someone could give me a little push

Tags: cordova, npm

I'm a fresh learner of cordova. I'm trying to build cross platform hybrid apps. But it came out with an error when I add android platform with `cordova platform add android`. I don't know how to deal with it.

```
No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.oorg/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-4.0.0.tgz
TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.
    at new CLient Request (_http_client.js:73:10)
    at Tunneling Agent.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
    at TunnelingAgent.createSocket(C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:117:25)
    at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:184:41)
    at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:80:8)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
    at Object.exports.request (https.js:136:15)
    at Request.start (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:594:30)
    at Request.end(C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:1186:28)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is a [bug](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/321) with Node and the CLI. The proposed solution is:

First of all, configure the proxy settings:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Replace the `tunnel-agent`'s content with this zip - [tunnel-agent](https://github.com/mikeal/tunnel-agent/archive/master.zip)

You have to locate your `tunnel-agent` folder at 2 places:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent
```

If you're on a 32-bit system and cannot find `Program Files (x86)`, check `Program Files` folder

Comment: Thank you very much.Change the tunnel-agent to the old version is not suit form me. Already tried and failed. It's a bug from Node.The problem was fixed by downgrading node from 0.12.0 to 0.10.33.